# How does the definition of a rigid body imply constant distance from the center of mass?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, reference-frames, rigid-body-dynamics, distance

Let there be a system of N point-particles in 3D space, this system is a rigid body. The general definition of a rigid body is $ \mid r_{i}-r_{j} \mid$=constant $\forall i,j$

In one of the books I was reading the property of a rigid body, that the distance between point and center of mass is constant for all particles, was used. How is this property derived?

Does $\frac{d}{dt} \mid {\bf{r}}_{i}-{\bf{r}}_{j}\mid=0 \space \forall i,j \Rightarrow \frac{d}{dt} \mid {\bf{R}} -{\bf{r}}_{i} \mid =0 \space \forall i$ where ${\bf{R}}=\frac{1}{M}\sum\limits_{i} {\bf{r}}_{i} m_{i}, M=\sum\limits_{i} m_{i}$ ?

If so, what is a proof of this?

Comment: By definition a rigid body is non-deformable. Therefore the distance between any two points of a rigid body is fixed

Comment: Yes, but the center of mass is not a point of the rigid body, generally speaking, so that the argued propery needs an explicit proof.

Answer (score 4):

Let us cosider the case of $N$ material points $\vec{x}_i$, with masses $m_i$, $i=1,2,\ldots, N$.

Let us denote by $\vec{G}$ the position of the center of mass and by $M$ the total mass.

$$M(\vec{G} - \vec{x}_1) = m_1\vec{x}_1+ m_2 \vec{x_2} + \cdots + m_N \vec{x}_N- m_1\vec{x}_1 - - m_2 \vec{x}_1 - \ldots - m_N\vec{x}_1$$ $$=  m_2(\vec{x}_2 - \vec{x_1}) +  m_3(\vec{x}_3 - \vec{x_1})+ \ldots  + m_N(\vec{x}_N - \vec{x_1})\:.$$
As a consequence
$$||\vec{G}_N - \vec{x}_1||^2 = M^{-2}\left(\sum_{j\neq 1}m^2_j ||\vec{x}_j-\vec{x}_1||^2  +  \sum_{i, j \neq 1\:, i\neq j} m_i m_j (\vec{x}_i -\vec{x}_1)\cdot (\vec{x}_j -\vec{x}_1) \right)$$
In the right-hand side the distances $||\vec{x}_j-\vec{x}_1||$ are constant in time by hypothesis.

However  also each scalar product $ (\vec{x}_i -\vec{x}_1)\cdot (\vec{x}_j -\vec{x}_1) $ is constant in time, just beacause
for $\vec{a}= \vec{x}_j - \vec{x}_1$ and $\vec{b}= \vec{x}_i - \vec{x}_1$,
we have $$-2\vec{a}\cdot \vec{b} = ||\vec{a}- \vec{b}||^2 - ||\vec{a}||^2 - ||\vec{b}||^2$$ and, in our case, the right hand side is constant in time as well. In particular $ ||\vec{a}- \vec{b}||^2  =  ||\vec{x}_i- \vec{x}_j||^2 $.

Evidently, the same proof is valid if replacing $\vec{x}_1$ for a generic $\vec{x}_k$.

Comment: This was a great answer, thank you! Should it not be $M^{-2}$ instead of $M^{-1}$ in the second equation however?

Comment: Yes, thank you for the correction.