# Mathematical Proof of consistency of centre of mass in a Rigid body

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, reference-frames, conservation-laws, rigid-body-dynamics

I read that the center of mass remains unchanged in its position with respect to other points in the rigid body, even when any external force is applied to the body. However, I am willing to know if there is any mathematical proof that establishes the constancy of the center of mass position relative to other points within a rigid body?

Comment: The body is rigid. How will the center of mass move anywhere?

Comment: _Any_ point that belongs to a rigid body remains fixed with respect to the rest of the points _by definition of a rigid body_.  What else is there two prove? If no points move, then why would the center of mass move in the body frame?

Comment: @John Alexiou I wanted a mathematical proof of it with respect to coordinate axes, but after thinking a little bit I got my solution, so no problem. Thanks

Comment: Does this answer ?https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/787700/how-does-the-definition-of-a-rigid-body-imply-constant-distance-from-the-center/787710#787710

Comment: @ValterMoretti That's the proof I was willing for, a big thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The definition of a "rigid body" is such that all points in the object's closure  remain at a constant position relative to other points of the body. Since this is true for any arbitrary point, then it is true for the center of mass as well.

Comment: The center of mass may not be a point of the body…

Answer (score 1):

Center of mass is a geometrical point within a rigid body.  Its position relative to other points in the body is independent of how body moves.